# Probleme avec variable phph dans button onclick js

Tags: javascript, php, variables, onclick

Tengo un script JS que muestra un texto corto y al hacer clic en el botón se muestra el texto largo. funciona muy bien con un valor fijo, pero cuando quiero poner una variable php, ya no funciona.
me podrian ayudar a resolver este problema
Creo que viene de la forma de integración de la variable en el JS, pero mi conocimiento en JS es limitado.

```js
function affichManipul(chaine_caratere){
    var t = '<?php echo $list_0; ?>';
    alert(t);
  if(document.getElementById('a_manipuler'+chaine_caratere).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('a_manipuler'+chaine_caratere).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('texte_court'+chaine_caratere).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('toaffich'+chaine_caratere).innerHTML = "&#32;&#32;&#32;-&#32;&#32;&#32;";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('a_manipuler'+chaine_caratere).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('texte_court'+chaine_caratere).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('toaffich'+chaine_caratere).innerHTML = "&#32;&#32;&#32;+&#32;&#32;&#32; ";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button_libro" style="align: center; " id="toaffich<?php echo $list;?>" 
            onclick="affichManipul(<?php echo $list;?>)">&#32;&#32;&#32;+&#32;&#32;&#32;</button>
    <span id="texto_corto<?php echo $list;?>" style="padding: 10px;">nivel cat <?php echo $list;?></span>
    <span id="a_manipuler<?php echo $list;?>" style="display: none">
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! el titulo no esta en español, no?

Comment: En `affichManipul(<?php echo $list;?>)` te faltan las comillas simples, así :  ----> `affichManipul(       '    <?php echo $list;?>     '      )`

Comment: El espació que puse no es necesario, pero es para que se notaran las comillas